# poset of lattice properties

Tags: co.combinatorics, order-theory, lattice-theory

Is there a good overview of the dependencies between properties that a (finite) lattice poset can have?

To give a practical example, I was looking for a property weaker than congruence uniform and stronger than semidistributive.

If I am not mistaken, https://graphclasses.org/ answers an analogous question for graphs.

Comment: Wikipedia has a very small diagram (about 20 different properties). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_of_lattices

Comment: For varieties of lattices there is a nice picture you can draw, since they are determined by their minimal excluded examples. (But e.g. semidistributive lattices do not form a variety.)

Comment: Extending my previous comment, I believe this webpage - https://www1.chapman.edu/~jipsen/gap/lambdaRL1.html - shows (the initial part of) the lattice of lattice varieties ordered by inclusion, but unfortunately it uses Java which no modern browser supports.

Comment: @SamHopkins, if you have Java installed on your computer then it probably includes an executable called appletviewer which does what the name suggests. The image it draws initially is https://i.stack.imgur.com/MacbG.png

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Thank you so much! But that makes me realize I linked to the (slightly) wrong page; I meant: https://www1.chapman.edu/~jipsen/gap/lambdaL.html. Could you produce a similar image for this page?

Comment: @SamHopkins, https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdepB.png . It's not the most readable image. I've found the structure encoded in the HTML of the page, so if someone wants to do a nicer image with graphviz then that would be the place to look for more useful labels.

Comment: @SamHopkins, I had graphviz open for something else, so while I was at it I [ported the second graph](https://gist.github.com/pjt33/ed03119fafef11a8041678cc1304f2e7).